# VGA switch 3 in 1 out

Tags: digital-logic, switches, output, vga

My team and I are going on a software development competition in 1 week. We will demonstrate the software on multiple laptops, but we have only one projector. So we need to be quickly able to switch between VGA inputs to the projector. And we need to have 3 inputs and 1 output. We know the basics of electronics, making PCBs... (our school has a electrical/computer technician course) All we need is the schematic. But we have not been able to find one. A 2-in 1-out would do too. We could just cascade two of those in a row. If you could help us we would be very thankful.

Comment: Such switches are available commercially; just go out and buy one. You may need to get a "KVM" (keyboard-video-mouse) switch and just use the video part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texas Instruments do a series of analogue switches for multiplexing VGA signals. [Here's](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scds317/scds317.pdf) one of them: -

[image]

They also do a 7-channel one [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3v712e.pdf) called the TS3V712E